# How To Convert Old Plutus Scripts to Vasil Reference Scripts?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, vasil-hard-fork, reference-scripts

One of the fun things, the Vasil hardfork gives us is the ability to reduce the size of transactions and so put more of them into a block (speeding up the chain).

My question is how to change the preexisting Plutus smart contracts I have written to take advantage of this? I think the following would be nice to have if you could point me to them please:

1. example of an old plutus contract and its vasil counterpart (highlighting the changes made and why)
2. A list of all possible changes I could make.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The existing V1 Plutus script just needs to be recompiled and serialised as V2. See this example of a minting policy serialised as both V1 and V2 for guidance, https://github.com/james-iohk/plutus-scripts/blob/master/src/TokenNamePolicy.hs.

Then you can create an output with the V2 script attached to be referenced in a transaction. See example using cardano-cli here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/scripts/babbage/example-babbage-script-usage.sh